# Graphics Issues in Ubuntu 14.04 Lenovo Thinkpad W540

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics, lenovo

I am recently having issues with my graphics and my computer is running comparatively slow.. I have the following error from my kernel:

```
cat  /var/log/kern.log | grep failed

[121792.821076] [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train] *ERROR* failed to enable link training
[121792.827083] [drm:intel_dp_complete_link_train] *ERROR* failed to start channel equalization
[121796.838749] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] init failed, -16
[166910.746085] [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train] *ERROR* failed to enable link training
[166910.752098] [drm:intel_dp_complete_link_train] *ERROR* failed to start channel equalization
[169118.271216] [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train] *ERROR* failed to enable link training
[169118.277014] [drm:intel_dp_complete_link_train] *ERROR* failed to start channel equalization
[169140.653737] Freezing of tasks failed after 20.006 seconds (1 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
[169140.727093] [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train] *ERROR* failed to enable link training
[169140.732969] [drm:intel_dp_complete_link_train] *ERROR* failed to start channel equalization
[169145.090743] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] init failed, -16
[169155.277671] [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train] *ERROR* failed to enable link training
[169155.283461] [drm:intel_dp_complete_link_train] *ERROR* failed to start channel equalization
[169328.691935] Freezing of tasks failed after 20.007 seconds (1 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
[169328.770065] [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train] *ERROR* failed to enable link training
[169328.775894] [drm:intel_dp_complete_link_train] *ERROR* failed to start channel equalization
[169362.526724] Freezing of tasks failed after 20.005 seconds (1 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
[169362.633597] [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train] *ERROR* failed to enable link training
[169362.639387] [drm:intel_dp_complete_link_train] *ERROR* failed to start channel equalization
[169403.965727] Freezing of tasks failed after 20.007 seconds (1 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
[169404.042353] [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train] *ERROR* failed to enable link training
[169404.048149] [drm:intel_dp_complete_link_train] *ERROR* failed to start channel equalization
[    0.235773] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_SUPPORT); disabling ASPM
[    7.532302] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] init failed, -16
[    0.389624] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_SUPPORT); disabling ASPM
[   85.143742] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -115
[    0.235796] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_SUPPORT); disabling ASPM
[    7.748205] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] init failed, -16
[    0.242944] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_SUPPORT); disabling ASPM
[    0.238618] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_SUPPORT); disabling ASPM
[    7.443180] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] init failed, -16
[    9.983506] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] init failed, -16
[ 3345.671018] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] init failed, -16
[    0.238784] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_SUPPORT); disabling ASPM
[    6.375705] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] init failed, -16
[    8.810912] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] init failed, -16
[    0.239961] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_SUPPORT); disabling ASPM
[    6.412908] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] init failed, -16
[    8.835804] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] init failed, -16
```

Similarly, the output from

```
sudo lshw -c video
```

is

```
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
   resources: irq:49 memory:b0000000-b0ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:90000000-91ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:b1000000-b107ffff
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:46 memory:b1400000-b17fffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

The output of

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

is

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd000011FCsv000017AAsd00002211bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-352 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-355 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-346 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-346-updates - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-340 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-340-updates - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

I had to fix frozen laptop because of the graphics error recently. Can you please find the cause of error and solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the latest stable NVIDIA driver and Optimus support from Proprietary GPU Drivers PPA :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Comment: He also has to remove the driver.

Comment: No - when you install it the way I described, the nouveau driver will automatically be blacklisted - uninstalling xserver-xorg-video-nouveau may break the operating system !

Comment: When the driver does not even exist, then it's not even necessary to blacklist. Ideally the user should do it from the driver management thing.

Comment: Removing xserver-xorg-video-nouveau may break X display server (GUI) - so the way I described to install nvidia, which blacklists nouveau driver automatically, is the safe advice !

Comment: 355 is a beta driver. 346 is an LTS driver that supports this adapter.

Comment: @Pilot6 - 355.06 was a beta driver - 355.11 from ppa is the current stable driver from the short-lived branch and supports the Quadro K2100M chip -> http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/90393/en-us

Comment: I used the above commands as well as selected the driver nvidia-355  from in both cases my computer didn't display GUI, I had to switch to command line to remove nvidia drivers before I got the GUI back again.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the drivers by running in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg-xserver-video-all
```

and it might work fine this way.